# Android webservice get out parameter

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

**My Webservice**

```
public int GetWayBillBySachetID( int version, string encryptedJsonIn, out string encryptedJsonOut )
{
  // some codes
  return number;
}
```

**Android**

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                OPERATION_NAME);
request.addProperty("version", "100");
request.addProperty("encryptedJsonIn", object.toString());
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
SOAP_ADDRESS);
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
}
```

My webservice is working fine but i'm unable to get the out parameter. When i check the response it only contains the returns value not out parameter. How i can get the out parameter. Please advice.

Comment: SoapObject response=(SoapObject) envelop.bodyIn; Try this. 
if (response != null) {
  Object o = response.getProperty("name of the parameter");

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was parameter issue. Nothing wrong with the code. Thanks.